# post form with an image to java rest webservice using cordova

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova, camera

We are developing a cordova app with jquery mobile and It supports iOS and Android platforms.

I have to post a complete form with few feilds and an Image (captured by cordova camera plugin and set in img tag source ) to an action url. e.g. action="http://someip/mobileserver/rest/main/process/form".

I have done rnd over it and it appears that we can only send image data with form values using [cordova file transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). As it requires change on webservice side, before proposing any change in webservice , i want to be sure if there is any other way to do it.

is it doable to send image on html form post with form data using Jquery? if yes, then any sample or example of sending image data along with form would be of great help.

Comment: As you use the camera to get the file, you can't just send the form, you have to use the file transfer plugin. But you don't have to change anything on the server, file transfer plugin send the image and the params as a multipart-form data

Comment: Thanks , will give it a try.